# I am trying to use a 2005 era library with MSVC 2013 but I am getting unresolved externals errors in Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, unresolved-external

**The setup:**
I have successfully compiled DarkGDK, a library designed for use with DirectX SDK 2007 and VS 2008, in VS 2013 with DirectX SDK 2010. I replaced one of the component libraries with a custom dummy library to resolve DirectX conflicts. I was able to successfully compile all of these component libraries.

**The Problem:**
When I compile my project that makes use of the DarkGDK libraries in Release mode, everything works as expected. I do get an message box complaining that the binary was built without debug information, but my program runs. However, in Debug mode, I get a number of errors. Below find a sample that I believe represents the lot well:

```
1>convmdl.lib(ConvMDL.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void __cdecl QuaternionSlerp(float const * const,float * const,float,float * const)" (?QuaternionSlerp@@YAXQBMQAMM1@Z)
1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>system.lib(CSystemC.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>system.lib(dxdiaginfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>convx.lib(ConvX.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>convmd3.lib(ConvMD3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(CBSPTree.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(CCompiler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(ProcessHSR.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>world.lib(Patch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(Universe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(cLightMaps.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(CSG.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(NVMeshMenderD3DX.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>image.lib(CImageC.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>animation.lib(CAnimation.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(DBOFormat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>basic3D.lib(CObjectManagerC.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>core.lib(RenderList.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>display.lib(CGfxC.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>file.lib(CFileC.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>sprites.lib(CSpriteManagerC.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>Debug\Weapon Creator 2 - Project Golden Girl.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I have been searching about this issue for a few days now. I have have checked all the projects' settings that belong to the DarkGDK library and my own project's settings. In Debug configuration they are all using "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)".

**TL;DR**
I am getting the above errors when attempting to compile a project in **Debug** configuration that uses the DarkGDK Library. All projects have the same Windows Library and C run time settings.

Thank you!

Edit: Errors changed to reflect Dauphic's contribution.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. Adding atls.lib does fix that one issue. Is there any problem using atls vs atlsd in Debug configuration?

Comment: You should use `atlsd` in debug and `atls` in release.

Comment: atlsd gives the following error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'atlsd.lib'

Comment: In Visual C++ 2013 there is no more atlsd.lib.  atls.lib may be used in both release and debug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing debug and release runtimes.

`__CrtDbgReportW` only exists in the debug runtime. If it's unresolved, it means you're probably compiling using the release runtime, but one of your libraries is using the debug runtime. You have to recompile one or the other, so they both use the same version.

You can find the runtime property at `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`

For the unresolved ATL symbol, I believe you need to link `atls.lib`.

Comment: In Visual C++ 2013 there is no more atlsd.lib.  atls.lib may be used in both release and debug builds.

Comment: I have checked all the projects' settings that belong to the DarkGDK library and my own project's settings. In Debug configuration they are all using "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)". The atls issue is solved, but the other link errors still stand. I am editing original post with full error messages.

Comment: My Goodness, it worked! I adjusted a few other things while I was in there, but I've got it compiling in both Debug and Release now! Thank you!

Comment: One last thing- When I compile in debug mode I get the following warning, and many more like it: `'Weapon Creator 2 - Project Golden Girl.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`   Should I be worried?

Comment: No, that just means your symbol server isn't set up, so you won't have symbols for system libraries. You can Google how to fix it, if you care.